# Calculate Grouped Average Percentage Using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need the last column AvgRecordCount to be the average of every two columns; see the first image for an example...

Any suggestions?

```
    SELECT l.AltName,
           CASE
                WHEN i.LabelTypeID = 1 THEN 'Generic'
                WHEN i.LabelTypeID = 2 THEN 'Brand'
           END AS LabelType,
           COUNT(i.LabelTypeID) as RecordCount
      FROM [RxTransaction] rxt
INNER JOIN Dimension.Item i 
        ON rxt.DispensedItemID = i.ItemID AND 
           rxt.LocationID = i.LocationID
INNER JOIN Dimension.Location l 
        ON rxt.LocationID = l.LocationId
     WHERE (i.LabelTypeID = 1 OR i.LabelTypeID = 2) AND
           rxt.DateFilled BETWEEN '12/1/2014' AND '12/31/2014'
  GROUP BY i.LabelTypeID, l.AltName
```

I'd like to see results like the items in this table, notice the new column percentage average across the two rows, generic/brand sets.
[image: I'd like to see results like the items in this table, notice the new column percentage average across the two rows, generic/brand sets.]

Image shows the SQL and current results, I want a new column that has each 2 rows percentage over each other.

[image: Image shows the SQL and current results, I want a new column that has each 2 rows percentage over each other.]

Comment: elaborate more on what you expect to see, provide a sample table of results you want

Comment: @DLeh has it exactly.  Please also do this in text not in images.  You may find that [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) is a useful tool to explain your needs.

Comment: I edited to add an example of what I'm looking to see...  tough to explain but I think I made it clear. I need an average for each location between the Generic and Brand usage.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by writing select statements for each of the calculated fields I needed... see below.

```
SELECT L.AltName, L.LocationId, COUNT(A.LabelTypeID) As TotalRecords,

(SELECT COUNT(i.LabelTypeID)
FROM [IntellectRX-DataWarehouse].[Fact].[RxTransaction] rxt
INNER JOIN Dimension.Item i on rxt.DispensedItemID = i.ItemID AND rxt.LocationID = i.LocationID
WHERE  i.LabelTypeID = 1 AND i.LocationID = L.LocationId AND
rxt.DateFilled between '12/1/2014' and '12/31/2014') As GenericTotal,


100
*
(SELECT COUNT(i.LabelTypeID)
FROM [IntellectRX-DataWarehouse].[Fact].[RxTransaction] rxt
INNER JOIN Dimension.Item i on rxt.DispensedItemID = i.ItemID AND rxt.LocationID = i.LocationID
WHERE  i.LabelTypeID = 1 AND i.LocationID = L.LocationId AND
rxt.DateFilled between '12/1/2014' and '12/31/2014')

/

(SELECT COUNT(i.LabelTypeID)
FROM [IntellectRX-DataWarehouse].[Fact].[RxTransaction] rxt
INNER JOIN Dimension.Item i on rxt.DispensedItemID = i.ItemID AND rxt.LocationID = i.LocationID
WHERE  (i.LabelTypeID = 1 OR i.LabelTypeID = 2) AND i.LocationID = L.LocationId AND
rxt.DateFilled between '12/1/2014' and '12/31/2014') As PercentAvg

FROM [IntellectRX-DataWarehouse].[Fact].[RxTransaction] B
INNER JOIN Dimension.Item A on B.DispensedItemID = A.ItemID AND B.LocationID = A.LocationID
INNER JOIN Dimension.Location L on B.LocationID = L.LocationId
WHERE  B.DateFilled between '12/1/2014' and '12/31/2014'
Group by L.AltName, L.LocationId
order by PercentAvg
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by with the exact CASE statement you have used in your select statement , something like....

```
SELECT l.AltName,
       CASE
            WHEN i.LabelTypeID = 1 THEN 'Generic'
            WHEN i.LabelTypeID = 2 THEN 'Brand'
       END AS LabelType,
   COUNT(i.LabelTypeID) as RecordCount
FROM [RxTransaction] rxt
INNER JOIN Dimension.Item i 
        ON rxt.DispensedItemID = i.ItemID AND 
           rxt.LocationID = i.LocationID
INNER JOIN Dimension.Location l 
        ON rxt.LocationID = l.LocationId
     WHERE (i.LabelTypeID = 1 OR i.LabelTypeID = 2) AND
           rxt.DateFilled BETWEEN '12/1/2014' AND '12/31/2014'
GROUP BY l.AltName,
       CASE
            WHEN i.LabelTypeID = 1 THEN 'Generic'
            WHEN i.LabelTypeID = 2 THEN 'Brand'
       END
```

Comment: I solved this by writing select statements for each of the calculated fields I needed... see below.